# @constructor in spring with dynamic parameters

Tags: spring, constructor, autowired

I have a requirement where I have to use spring autowiring to call a class constructor.

The old code is as below -

```
public void method(String arg){
 MyClass obj = new MyClass(arg);
 System.out.println("Constructor called with parameter : " + obj.toString());
}
```

I have to change the above code into the spring. I have gone through the tutorial on sprinsource but was not able to find the solution.

I am new to spring framework so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a web or a desktop application?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov It is a web app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a method, not a constructor.
Also, there is plenty of material on the web if you search.
e.g. [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/05/14/annotation-driven-dependency-injection-in-spring-21/)

Comment: yes, it is a method but inside method a constructor is called with a parameter (There is also a default constructor - so total 2 constructors). I am struggling to find out how to call the appropriate constructor inside the method through spring. I will go through the link provided by you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could benefit from [*3.4.6.1 Lookup method injection*](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html). However it currently does not support parametrized constructors, see [SPR-7431](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7431) - this tickets will most likely be fixed in Spring 3.2.

See also [my article](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html) describing that feature.